# Обмен информацией по WiFi без подключения

Tags: wifi

Всем здравствуйте!
Есть ли возможность передавать полезную нагрузку по WiFi без подключения.
Возможно в hello пакете, где мы представляемся друг другу или каким-нибудь "расширенным" пингом? В терминологии не очень силен.
Направьте или подскажите, возможно, есть уже решения на данную тему?

*Зачем? Находясь уже в сети, возможность обмениваться информацией с другими устройствами из другой сети.

Всем огромное спасибо!

Comment: С другими устройствами **из другой сети** не выйдет - у вас нет маршрутизируемого адреса, его вам выдадут только после авторизации на точке доступа.

Comment: Но мы же видим это устройство в списке сетей? Значит можем ему что-то отправить, не так ли? Хотя бы запрос на подключение. Почему бы вместо это запроса не отправить ему команду. Шифрование отложим на потом.

Answer (score 5):

## Обмениваться — вряд ли. Слушать — теоретически...

1. **Если** все адаптеры принимающих и драйверы для них имеют "режим слежения" (monitor mode), позволяющий слушать абсолютно все пакеты, идущие *по одному каналу* Wi-Fi. Другие возможности при этом могут быть ограничены.
2. **Если** пакеты передаются незашифрованными.
3. **Если** сети, между которыми планируется взаимодействие, находятся *на одном канале* Wi-Fi (следствие первого пункта):

   - Чего обычно избегают, т. к. разные сети на одном канале мешают работе друг друга (снижают производительность/дальность).

...но такую ситуацию можно разве что создать самостоятельно, "в природе" такое не встречается.

Это если предполагать, что у каждого клиента только один Wi-Fi-адаптер. Если есть несколько, они могут работать независимо друг от друга и передавать пакеты между собой. Но это банально.

Comment: Первый клиент - телефон или планшет, соответственно одна сетевая карта, один поток. Защита/шифрование - можно подумать в последствии, так как сначала нужен принцип. Что смотреть? Я правильно понимаю, если есть устойчивое соединение, то возможности обмена данными уже ограничены? Мне много не нужно, не видео и не звук, элементарный бинар.

Comment: @Alexander выясняйте, у кого из них есть monitor mode и доступ к нему. Если только у одного из них, связь выйдет односторонней, если вообще выйдет.

Comment: Я читал, что BLE обмениваются дополнительным пакетом, то есть например говорит "Я бикон от эппла". Можно это использовать? Например с подменной  SSID после каждого успешного совершенного действия. У всех дейвасов из Anroid и iPhone/* есть возможность слежения за сетями, об этом и вопрос, как его использовать. Еще хотелось бы понять, можно ли, зная алгоритм, все это проводить в невидимом режиме?

Comment: @Alexander раз в 100 мс (обычно) точки доступа заявляют о себе с помощью [beacon frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beacon_frame), вопрос в том, кто их услышит. Устройства, не подключенные ни к какой сети, переключаются между каналами и ищут эти фреймы. В теории, в этих фреймах можно передавать какую-то полезную нагрузку, но опять же, это односторонняя связь, т. к. ответить на них (штатным образом) нельзя. Если хотите больше внутренних деталей, можете задать вопрос на [NE.SE](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/), т. к. я знаю не так уж много :)

Comment: И нет, "следящий режим" это не то же самое, что "режим поиска сетей". Последний есть у всех (что я видел). А вот первый не столь распорстранён.

Comment: Я понял. Вы уже знаете больше из всех моих знакомых) Спасибо за ссылки. Я правильно понял, у каждой точки доступа есть свой резерв на hello пакет, то есть есть payload - где они представляются, и еще резерв, которым они смогут "подписаться" более субъективно? Обратная связь важный вопрос, но дело в том, что такие команды работают когда видно результат, так что все это можно сбросить на погрешность, так как основной идентификатор это Зрение или Слух. "Штатным образом" - то есть, если в этом пакете передать (изменить) пакет, мы можем отследить изменение состояния?

Comment: Большую часть этого я узнал час назад, отдалённо зная касательные темы :) Нет, у точек доступа нет никаких резервов, они либо работают на разных каналах, либо дерутся за пропускную способность на одном, создавая друг другу помехи и регулярно переотправляя данные. Если точка поменяет свой SSID, то в очередном beacon frame будет новая информация, и те, кто сканирует диапазон на предмет сетей, вскоре увидят новый. Отследить изменение можно. Отправить что-то в ответ, не подключаясь -- нет. Вмешаться в процедуру подключения -- тоже скорее всего нет, из-за драйвера.

Comment: Немного не так. Я уже знаю, что моя точка доступа будет иметь SSID согласно - id_1, id_2, id_3, etc. В зависимости от состояний. Подождите, но кроме имени точки доступа представляются - мак адрес и тп. У блютуса точно все описано в протоколе, когда они соединяются с homekit. То есть идентифицируют "Своих". Это же наша возможность для передачи данных?  Разве нет? https://docs.zentri.com/zentrios/wz/3.1/cmd/apps/multiclient-wlan

Comment: @Alexander попытаться можно, но это нештатный способ применения и нужно быть готовым к тому, что на типичной стандартоуважающей принимающей стороне сложившуюся ситуацию будет невозможно обработать :)

Comment: А понял. Значит копать просто в протокол первичного обращения? Нет каких-то наработок на этот счет? *Мне кажется они сами к этому придут, с учетом большого обновления и WiFi и Bluetooth в следующем году, которые они анонсировали. Ведь они обе метят в IoT.

Comment: Звук также бы нестандартным средством коммуникации, но справились. Много устройств с таким способом общения. Мне кажется тема может быть интересной.

Comment: @Alexander вы, похоже, собрались куда-то в область меш-сетей, пытаясь натянуть их на технологии, изначально созданные для совсем других целей и потому имеющие сознательно созданные ограничения. Эти ограничения будут вам мешать. Не удивляйтесь :) Если Wi-Fi и BT когда-то тоже будут поддерживать это, начнётся это с расширения существующих стандартов, потом поддержки этих расширений железом, драйверами и прикладным ПО, и только тогда сможет использоваться широкой общественностью. Но не ранее.